# Comparing dissimilarity measures

Tags: clustering, similarities

I have 50 objects and several ways of measuring dissimilarity between them. I would like to compare behaviour of these dissimilarity measures on my objects (which of them yield similar results and which do not). Is there a way to do it?
If needed, dissimilarities can be approximated with Euclidean distances in k-dimensional space using MDS.

Comment: How to compare the dissimilarity measures depends on what you're trying to do with them. You included the 'clustering' tag, so are you trying to find dissimilarity measures that lead to similar clustering of the data points?

Comment: Actually, I thought clustering can help in comparing dissimilarity measures (performing clustering with different dissimilarities and then somehow comparing clusterings instead of dissimilariities). But I was hoping for some more rigorous approach that directly compares how objects are "positioned" relative to each other.

Comment: In case someone else is interested, I have found that Mantel test and Distatis method do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the *correlation* between the distances, or (often better)between the ranks for the neighbors of each object.

The average will give you an "average (rank-) correlation" between any two distance measures. Then you can identify similar measures.

I have seen such an analysis in a paper, but I'd need to search it. It was a few hears ago.